# Наследование в Javascript

Tags: ооп, javascript

```
TwoDShape.prototype = new Shape();
TwoDShape.prototype.constructor = TwoDShape;
```

В книге Стефанова про ООП написано, что вторая строчка нужна для того, чтобы не было негативных последствий, т.к. свойство `constructor` ненадежно. Непонятно следующее: зачем присваивать `prototype.constructor'у` именно `TwoDShape`, а не `Object` (или `Shape`, так как он родитель)? По сути прототип - это объект-родитель, на который ссылается `TwoDShape.prototype`... Вроде как и конструктор должен быть именно родительский (т.е. либо `Shape`, либо `Object`).

Comment: сначало присваиваете прототипу исходного класса прототип родительского, потом дописываете ( если надо ) свойства и(или) методы исходного класса. Если надо рассширятся от исходного все примерно тоже самое.

Answer (score 1):

prototype - свойство функции-конструктора, указывающее на объект, на основе которого она делает новые объекты. Не в том смысле, что содержит предка функции-конструктора, а в том, что содержит предка для всех объектов, которые эта функция создаст.
constructor - свойство объекта, указывающее на функцию, которой он сделан.

```
TwoDShape.prototype = new Shape();
```

ставит в качестве объекта-основы объект-результат работы функции Shape, включающий в том числе и свойство constructor, которое указывает что объект сделала функция Shape.

```
new TwoDShape()
```

создаст объект, в свойстве constructor которого будет указано что он создан функцией Shape. Чтобы было правильно указано, что он сделан функцией TwoDShape, делают

```
TwoDShape.prototype.constructor = TwoDShape;
```

Вообще, сам механизм прототипного наследования реализовани через скрытое свойство `__proto__`, это в нем хранится ссылка на объект-прототип и это цепочку этих объектов javascript проходит при поиске свойств и методов. А constructor просто указывает функцию, которой был создан объект, и вроде ничего больше. Если его менять, то будет указывать правильную, если нет - то функцию, создавшую самый верхний объект в цепочке прототипов.

Comment: Замечу, что свойство ( оно не скрытое, а системное ) называется [[Prototype]], и некоторые браузеры его могут показывать через свойство объекта `__proto__`

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите создать объект класса - то вы вызываете его конструктор ( явно или не явно )
Поэтому и так...

P.S - Лично я против такого подхода, т.к. считаю это не логичным... 
Если не вдаваться в подробности, то так:

```
Obj = function (){ /*Реальный конструктор*/ };

(function Extend(){
  ObjPrototype = function (){ /*Конструктор получения объекта прототипа*/ };
  ObjPrototype.prototype = Parent.prototype;
  Obj.prototype = new ObjPrototype();
  Obj.prototype.constructor = Obj;
  delete ObjPrototype;
})();
```

Comment: Это вроде ясно... но почему во второй строчке в конце указан TwoDShape. Если prototype - это ссылка на родительский объект, то и TwoDShape.prototype.constructor должен указывать на конструктор родительского объекта

Comment: В вашем предложении не остаётся ссылки на конструктор порождающего класса

Comment: Я про то, что логичнее было писать вместо указанного в самом начале вот так:
TwoDShape.prototype = new Shape();
TwoDShape.prototype.constructor = Shape; //здесь в конце строчки по идее должен быть Shape а не TwoDShape, но у автора не так

Comment: Не могу сказать, зачем нужен `prototype.constructor` ( т.к. при **`new`** он не вызывается таким образом ), но такая традиция)<br>
P.S: Создать такой-же объект:
    
    Obj2 = new Obj1.constructor();

Comment: Минус за глобальные переменные и невозможность повторного использования кода наследования в текущем его вида